# ReactJS -> store variable from promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, promise, google-geocoder

I'm trying to figure out how to store promise return stages into variables. In this use case, I'm using google maps and google's geocoder to transform a JSON file of addresses into an array of lat lng objects in order to make markers, but I'm curious regardless. It's been done through a single promise, but as I'm forced to loop through the data and execute the call, I can't call another function and leave the promise, as I have to repeat the promise eventually. This means I need to store the object in a separate variable. See the sections of code below.

address.json

```
{ 
  "address" : "Oosterpark 9",
  "city" : "Amsterdam",
  "name" : "Onze Lieve Vrouwe Gasthuis"
  "zipcode" : "1091 AC"
},
{
  "address" : "Jan Tooropstraat 164",
  "city" : "Amsterdam",
  "name" : "Sint Lucas Andreas Hospital"
  "zipcode" : "1061 AE"
}
```

Map.js

```
makeMarker(a){
    Geocode.setApiKey(this.apiKey);
    let arr = [];
    for(let i=0; i < a.length; i++){
        let address = b[i].address.replace(" ","+") + ',+'+b[i].zipcode.replace(" ","+")+',+'+b[i].city;

        arr[i] = Geocode.fromAddress(address).then(
            response => {
                const {lat, lng} = response.results[0].geometry.location;
                console.log(lat, lng);
                return {lat: lat, lng: lng};
            }
        );
    }
return arr;
}
```

In this case the above function is called on in the constructor where a variable is waiting to be defined by the outcome of the makeMarker function. In this case, it only returns [promise, promise], when it's supposed to return [{lat: __, lng: __,}, {lat: __, lng: __,}].

I hope to hear some of your ideas on how to solve this use case!

Comment: `makeMarker` is called in the constructor?

Comment: I've since moved it to render function, i just called it in constructor to get the function running before I make my render function return anything.

Comment: You can make use of Promise.all([promise, promise]).then(callback), see ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), create an array of promises on the instance of the `class`, then on `componentDidMount` (or other useful life cycle hook) run:

```
Promise.all(promies).then(...)
```

So something like this:

```
makeMarker(a){
    Geocode.setApiKey(this.apiKey);
    let arr = [];
    for(let i=0; i < a.length; i++){
        let address = b[i].address.replace(" ","+") + ',+'+b[i].zipcode.replace(" ","+")+',+'+b[i].city;

        arr[i] = Geocode.fromAddress(address)
    }
    this.promises = arr;
}
```

Then elsewhere in your code:

```
Promise.all(this.promises).then(
  listOfResponses => {
     // rest of your code
  }
)
```

---

Here is a small example of such usage with `Promise.all`

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fetchedData: []
    }
    this.promises = data.map(d => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(d),1500);
      })
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all(this.promises).then(fetchedData => this.setState({ fetchedData }));
  }
  
  render() {
    const { fetchedData } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {fetchedData.length ? fetchedData.map(d => <div>{d}</div>) : "Loading..."}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Promise.all seemed to do the trick. It allowed me to change the state and load in markers afterwards. I think i'm still bound by having to drop variables within the state of react, unfortunately. I'm hoping there's a way where I can just assign it to a single variable. This way I can avoid state changes and render in one state

Comment: But that promise could take some time to resolved right? By this time the render will get invoked at least once. In order to display the result, another render must be invoked. Or am i missing your goal?

Comment: I'm speaking more in terms of other case studies. In this case study it works flawlessly, however say I wanted to manually load in markers would I be able to call the promise.all when I need it?

Comment: A promise will resolve only once.
When using `.then` its your way to push callbacks that will run after it will get resolved. You can  place that code anywhere you want.

Comment: No problems. Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

@Sagiv b.g' s answer of using Promise.all is the best way. 
Here is another approach.

```js
var arr = [];
makeMarker(a){
    Geocode.setApiKey(this.apiKey);
   
    for(let i=0; i < a.length; i++){
        let address = b[i].address.replace(" ","+") + ',+'+b[i].zipcode.replace(" ","+")+',+'+b[i].city;

        Geocode.fromAddress(address).then(
            response => {
                const {lat, lng} = response.results[0].geometry.location;
                console.log(lat, lng);
                 addToArr({lat: lat, lng: lng},b);
            }
        );
    }

}

addToArr(latLongObj,b){
  arr.push(latLongObj);
  if(arr.length >= b.length){
    //callYourfunction and do the logic
  }
}
```